# How to change dynamically with jquery the background of a div in a site made in wordpress?

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

I have a site made in wordpress. Each page of the site has a dynamic header where the background of a div changes every six seconds with the fade in effect

The code I made I work perfectly on the home page but it has errors in the other pages.

I am getting the website url in order to  concat two strings: website url and the name of image.  So with jquery change the background image every six seconds.

The problem is the url in the internal pages is taken all the path. Example:

In the home page the url works perfectly gives me this result:  "localhost/sitepage" + "wp-content/uploads/2019/05/slider_1.1.png" = "localhost/sitepage/wp-content/uploads/2019/05/slider_1.1.png"

In the rest of the pages gives me the next result:   "localhost/sitepage/about/localhost/sitepage/wp-content/uploads/2019/05/slider_1.1.png"

Being the "localhost/sitepage/about/" the current page concat with  the result I want localhost/sitepage/wp-content/uploads/2019/05/slider_1.1.png

this is my code:

```
var pageURL = jQuery(location).attr("href");

var img = pageURL+"wp-content/uploads/2019/05/slider_1.1.png";
var img2 = pageURL+"wp-content/uploads/2019/05/slider_1.1.png"; 

var interval = setInterval(function() { 

if(img == img2){


img=pageURL+"wp-content/uploads/2019/05/slider_1.png";

}else{

img=pageURL+"wp-content/uploads/2019/05/slider_1.1.png";

}

console.log(img);
jQuery('#headerhome').fadeTo('slow', 0.3, function()
{
   jQuery(this).css('background-image', 'url(' + img + ')');
}).delay(2500).fadeTo('slow', 1);
```

When the function console.log prints the value inside img variable shows the url perfectly as I want:

localhost/sitepage/wp-content/uploads/2019/05/slider_1.1.png

But in the  browser console appears the following error

error 404 get localhost/sitepage/about/localhost/sitepage/wp-content/uploads/2019/05/slider_1.1.png

What can i do?

Comment: you can start the URL with http://   `'url(http://' + img + ')'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently your pageURL shows the entire url, which would include the 'about' permalink. Since Wordpress image files are located off the domain's 'wp-content' folder, what you need is a static domain name without the permalink (e.g. 'about').

I'm presuming you want pageURL to show 'localhost/sitepage' when testing on localhost and 'www.example.com' when on production site.

If so, try this?

```
var url = window.location.href; 
var hostname = (new URL(url)).hostname; //returns either 'localhost' or 'www.example.com';
var pageURL = (hostname === 'localhost')? 'localhost/sitepage':'www.example.com';

...
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your pageURL to the following:

```
var pageURL = jQuery(location).attr("href");
```

to

```
var pageURL = document.location.href;
```